# Does every partially ordered commutative ring admit an order preserving homomorphism to a real closed field?

Tags: ring-theory, ordered-fields

I hope the answer is yes. It would suffice to construct a homomorphism to a formally real field. I think it would then suffice to extend the partial order to a total ring order, but I'm not sure if this is possible, nor am I sure if this would actually suffice.